# Converting NOT in into LEFT join giving incorrect results

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, left-join, amazon-athena

Please help me in converting following NOT in query to Left join as I want a date column in select clause. I have to use this query as source to Amazon quicksight. Quicksight cannot pass date paramters created in report to my source query. So I have to get date filtering condition in WHERE clause.

Not in:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Date(h.Created_Date) DATE, ( h.Vehicle_ID)Decline
FROM awsdatacatalog.waves.Recurring_Transaction_History h  
Left JOIN awsdatacatalog.waves.Wash_Invoice wi  on h.invoice_id=wi.invoice_id

WHERE Date(h.Created_Date) BETWEEN date('2021-05-01') AND date('2021-05-01')

AND h.Status IN ('Declined','DECLINED')
AND h.Vehicle_ID NOT IN (
SELECT Distinct ut.vehicle_Id
FROM awsdatacatalog.waves.Unlimited_Wash_Transaction ut 
WHERE   (Is_Refunded IS NULL OR CAST(Is_Refunded AS INTEGER) =0)
AND (Status ='RECURRING' or Status ='RESIGNUP')
AND DATE(DATE) BETWEEN date('2021-05-01') AND date('2021-05-01')
)
```

Left join query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Date(h.Created_Date) DATE, ( h.Vehicle_ID)Decline
FROM awsdatacatalog.waves.Recurring_Transaction_History h  
Left JOIN awsdatacatalog.waves.Wash_Invoice wi  on h.invoice_id=wi.invoice_id
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT Distinct ut.vehicle_Id, DATE(DATE) DATE
FROM awsdatacatalog.waves.Unlimited_Wash_Transaction ut 
WHERE   (Is_Refunded IS NULL OR CAST(Is_Refunded AS INTEGER) =0)
AND (Status ='RECURRING' or Status ='RESIGNUP')

) A
ON  H.Vehicle_ID = A.Vehicle_ID
AND  DATE(h.Created_Date) <= A.DATE
WHERE Date(h.Created_Date) BETWEEN date('2021-05-01') AND date('2021-05-01')
 AND A.Vehicle_ID IS NULL
 AND A.DATE IS NULL
AND h.Status IN ('Declined','DECLINED')
ORDER BY Date(h.Created_Date) , ( h.Vehicle_ID)
```

Comment: Queries looks different. 1. i can see `AND  DATE(h.Created_Date) <= A.DATE` extra in second qry. 2. in first sql, you are filtering like `AND DATE(DATE) BETWEEN date('2021-05-01') AND date('2021-05-01')` in first not in clause but in second scenario, its not there like first one.

Comment: Yes placed an equi join earlier AND  DATE(h.Created_Date) = A.DATE but it was not calculating between operator values correctly so I placed this <= symbol. basically what i wanted to do was filter the NOT IN subquery with same date range what I did with  H.created_date

Comment: Then remove it and add `AND DATE(DATE) BETWEEN date('2021-05-01') AND date('2021-05-01')
)` inside the subquery like your first qry

Comment: Keep in mind that anytime you add a condition to your WHERE, other than a NULL check, on a table that is LEFT JOINed, you have effectively turned it back into an INNER JOIN.